# I want to print variable in string which is writen by user

Tags: python, string, input, string-formatting

```
name = input('enter the name of the coustomer : ',),
days = int(input('enter the  number of days for :'))
```

I want to print name after the text enter the number of days for (name) (type by user )

Comment: Using an f-string: `days = int(input(f'enter the number of days for {name}: '))`

Answer (score 1):

```
 name = input('enter the name of the coustomer : ')
```

Here you have a `name` variable of type `str` given by the built-in function `input`.

```
print(name)
```

You can print it with the built-in function `print`.

---

> I want to print name after the text enter the number of days for (name) (type by user )

You can re-use the `name` variable with an `f-string`:

```
days = int(input(f'enter the  number of days for {name}:'))
```

Even if it's the best practice, `f-string` isn't the only way to format a `str`ing in Python, and if you want it to work for versions older than `3.6`, you can do something like this:

```
days = int(input('enter the  number of days for {}:'.format(name)))
```